# Style Option in Selectbox using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I need your help.

I am dynamically adding options to a select box using the code below. However, how can I add a style each option in the select box using javascript? and doing it dynamically?

```
var status = new Array()
status[0] = ""
status[1] = "ACTIVE"
status[2] = "ON HOLD"
status[3] = "CLOSED"
for (i=0; i<status.length; i++) { document.getElementById('status').options[i]=new Option(status[i], i) }
```

ie.)
[DROP DOWN MENU]
ACTIVE (text color is green)
ON HOLD (text color is yellow)
CLOSED (text color is red)

Thanks for all your help and support.

Cheers,

Jay

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can style each element independently, or you can set up css classes beforehand and assign the classname to the element.

Check out this fiddle, make sure to select option 2 in the dropdown:
http://jsfiddle.net/xdXFz/

Optionally, [see how to dynamically create select with options](http://supunk.blogspot.com/2009/01/creating-select-list-using-javascript.html):

Sample:

```
var statuses = ["", "ACTIVE", "ON HOLD", "CLOSED"];
var elSelect = document.getElementById("status");

for ( var i = 0; i < statuses.length; i++ ){

    var elOption = document.createElement("option");
        // ex: Assign a css class to the option
        elOption.setAttribute('class', 'Your_CSS_Classname_Here');
        
        // ex: style the option
        elOption.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
        
        // set the value of the option
        elOption.setAttribute("value", statuses[i]);
        
        // set the text that displays for the option
        elOption.innerHTML = statuses[i];
    
    // add the option to your select dropdown
    elSelect.appendChild(elOption);

}
```

Comment: Your first link is to this question that your answering. Was that deliberate?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
var status = new Array()
status[0] = ""
status[1] = "ACTIVE" 
status[2] = "ON HOLD" 
status[3] = "CLOSED"

var s1 = status[1];
var s2 = status[2];
var s3 = status[3];

if (s1) {
  //style here
}
else if (s2) {
  //style here
}
else if (s3) {
  //style here
}

for (i=0; i<status.length; i++) { document.getElementById('status').options[i]=new Option(status[i], i) }
```

Not anywhere near tested or refined.